# How to Display the Members of a Class

Tags: c#, linq, tostring

I'm trying to create a wrapper for selecting multiple items from a single array.  I get the result at the end of the code below.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Tester.cs
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var customers = new[] 
        {
            new { CustomerID = 1, FirstName = "Orlando", LastName = "Gee",
            CompanyName = "A Bike Store" },
            new { CustomerID = 2, FirstName = "Keith", LastName = "Harris",
            CompanyName = "Bike World" },
            new { CustomerID = 3, FirstName = "Donna", LastName = "Carreras",
            CompanyName = "A Bike Store" },
            new { CustomerID = 4, FirstName = "Janet", LastName = "Gates",
            CompanyName = "Fitness Hotel" },
            new { CustomerID = 5, FirstName = "Lucy", LastName = "Harrington",
            CompanyName = "Grand Industries" },
            new { CustomerID = 6, FirstName = "David", LastName = "Liu",
            CompanyName = "Bike World" },
            new { CustomerID = 7, FirstName = "Donald", LastName = "Blanton",
            CompanyName = "Grand Industries" },
            new { CustomerID = 8, FirstName = "Jackie", LastName = "Blackwell",
            CompanyName = "Fitness Hotel" },
            new { CustomerID = 9, FirstName = "Elsa", LastName = "Leavitt",
            CompanyName = "Grand Industries" },
            new { CustomerID = 10, FirstName = "Eric", LastName = "Lang",
            CompanyName = "Distant Inn" }
                        };

        var addresses = new[] { 
            new { CompanyName = "A Bike Store", City = "New York", Country = "United States"},
            new { CompanyName = "Bike World", City = "Chicago", Country = "United States"},
            new { CompanyName = "Fitness Hotel", City = "Ottawa", Country = "Canada"},
            new { CompanyName = "Grand Industries", City = "London", Country = "United Kingdom"},
            new { CompanyName = "Distant Inn", City = "Tetbury", Country = "United Kingdom"}
        };

        IEnumerable<Names> customerfullName = customers.Select(data => new Names { 
        FirstName = data.FirstName,
        LastName = data.LastName});

        foreach (Names entry in customerfullName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }  
    }
} 
    class Names
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tester.cs.Names is what i get repeated when I run the program.

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default the ToString will be used, use:

```
class Names
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

It's also possible to create an extra property for the fullname

```
class Names
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
foreach (Names entry in customerfullName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine` uses the `ToString` method of the `object` class. By default, that displays the name of the class.

This method is overridden by classes derived from `object` to display whatever they want. You have not overridden it, so you get the default.

You can reproduce your problem, without LINQ, as follows:

```
class Names
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

var name = new Names {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Saunders"};
Console.WriteLine(name);  // Will display "Tester.cs.Names"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Names` class has not overridden the `ToString` method, so it is using the default implementation from `object` and printing out it's type name.  You either need to override `ToString` in `Names` to print out the underlying strings, or you need to print out the individual string properties in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: which would you suggest as the best choice?

Comment: @n00blearner Either is fine.  Try both and decide for yourself.